# Django admin logging out on model save

Tags: django, session, django-admin

I'm running a Django app for my root public_html folder, and it's working fine. But there's a problem with one of my other apps. The problematic app is accessed through a redirect to a subdirectory (e.g. http://workingsite.com redirects to public_html, http://brokensite.com redirects to public_html/foo)

The problem is that the session expires whenever anything needs to be saved in the Django admin (either added or changed). If you try again, sometimes it works. This does not happen on my own machine when I run the Django dev server.

The timezone in both of the app settings.py files is the same, which is the same as the timezone in both of the .htaccess files.

The apps are almost identical, except the working app uses WYMEditor and the broken one uses TinyMCE as its text editor. Don't know why that would do anything to cause the problem, but I included it just in case. Also, I've made a custom CSS file for the admin backend in the broken app (again, shouldn't cause a problem).

Comment: Also, sometimes when trying to access http://brokensite.com (either the admin or the site proper) I get redirected to the 404 for http://workingsite.com

The site seems to work only about half the time.

Comment: is the settings.SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN set correctly?

Comment: it looks like you have 2 sites on he same server and sometimes redirected between them

Comment: I think the host was doing some maintenance - it seems to have fixed itself... I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have been a configuration issue with the company I was hosting with - it's not happening anymore.