# Django admin suddenly logging out only on production environment (Refused to execute script because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable)

Tags: python, django, django-admin, mime-types, mime

Whenever i do an operation like save, update or filter something on my django admin, there's a chance of get redirect to login page and it's required to loging again. This behaviour occurs very often, but the odd thing is: it only occur's on production enviorment. I'm running the aplication on an *ECS cluster* with *AWS fargate*. When i check the browser storage, there are 3 cookies: `csrftoken`, `sessionid` and `djdt`. all of them with a large expiration time ( at least one week ).

My **settings.py** has the following session configuration:

```
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = 'sessions'
# The module to store session data
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
# A string like "example.com", or None for standard domain cookie.
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = env.str('SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN', default=None)
# Whether the session cookie should be secure (https:// only).
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = not DEBUG
# why it doesn't resolve the sundenly logout problem!?
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE= 24*60*60*7
```

I tried the following issues, but they doesn't work for me:

- [Django development server keeps logging out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247190/django-development-server-keeps-logging-out)
- [Django admin logging out on model save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497148/django-admin-logging-out-on-model-save)

any help will be apreciated

**EDIT**
I figured out some important clue:

before i get redirect, the following error raise on browser's console:

```
Refused to execute script from '<my_url>/jsl18n' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled
```

after the error message get displayed, any click or interaction with the admin result in a redirect to login's page.
i use some very simple JS files on admin to hide/show some fields based on user interaction. I think this massage has some relationship with theses static js files. I found some issues with this exact error message, and it's look like not django specific. But the issues didn't help me at all.

Answer (score 4):

Finally i figured it out. I have changed my `settings.py`:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'

CACHES = {
    'default': env.cache(
        'CACHES_DEFAULT_URL', default='locmemcache://cache-default'),
    'sessions': env.cache(
        'CACHES_SESSIONS_URL', default='locmemcache://cache-sessions'),
    'memory': env.cache(
        'CACHES_MEMORY_URL', default='locmemcache://cache-memory'),
}
```

to:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
```

I don't know exactly why it works but maybe the local memory cache strategy isn't a good choice on a cluster environment. If anybody has a better guess, please let me know.